# How to generate dict in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and i would like help:
My little script:

```
def get_link():

    #My datas
    dict = {}
    dict['Label1'] = 'URL1'
    dict['Label2'] = 'URL2'

    return [{'label': l, 'url': u} for l, u in dict.iteritems()]


get_link()
```

So, the problem is at the end. How to return the result as i want ?

> a = {'label': 'Label1', 'uri': 'URL1'},{'label': 'Label2', 'uri':
>   'URI2'},...

Comment: So for your end result you want `a` to be a `list` of `dict`s?

Comment: Presumably `a` is a list? Including the real code you're running, rather than an arbitrary snippet, will help you get better answers. You also don't say *what* "the problem" is. Are you getting a syntax error? A stack trace? Incorrect behavior? What's wrong?

Comment: You have some syntax errors, the append is a method, and you assigned value to it, there is no `a` and you trying to append to it, you return a value but that not in a function code block.

Comment: I would like a  is a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from your question, there is always an association between a label and a value. So I suggest to store both in a single dictionary and not spread the information in two independent structures:

```
dict = {}
dict['Label1'] = 'URL1'
dict['Label2'] = 'URL2'
```

And to output it, you can use a simple loop:

```
[{'label': l, 'url': u} for l, u in dict.items()]
```

Of course this solution only makes sense, if for a given label there is only one URL. Otherwise, you need to turn your dictionary into a list to which you append label/url pairs.

Comment: Yes, for a given label there is only one URL. I will test your code

Comment: `def get_link():

 #My datas
 dict = {}
 dict['Label1'] = 'URL1'
 dict['Label2'] = 'URL2'

 [{'label': l, 'url': u} for l, u in a.iteritems()]
 

get_link()` #a is not defined

Comment: Just replace `a` with `dict` and you are fine to go. And return the last line if you put it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the return statement unless you actually have a function

Otherwise you can use dict-comprehension

```
a = {'label': label[i], 'uri': uri[i] for i in range(len(label)) }
```

Though, realistically, you should store the labels and urls together in a list from the start...

```
a = [] 
a.append( ('label', 'url',) )
```

Answer (score 1):

## hope this helps

```
def urlAndLables():
    label = {}
    uri = {}

#My datas
    label[0] = 'Label1'
    uri[0] = 'URL1'

    label[1] = 'Label2'
    uri[1] = 'URL2'

    #Check if list is valid
    if(len(label) != len(uri)):
        print("Error label or uri missing")

    a=[]

    for i in range(len(label)):
        a.append({label[i], uri[i]})

    return a
if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_dict = urlAndLables()
    print (new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement is valid only inside a function. Move your code into a function. Besides your code is broken anyway and is not very clear what yo intend to do.